# Convert Excel file to json with XLSX javascript library

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, excel, xlsx

I want to get an excel file and parse it into a json so I can send it to the backend as a string object.

I import the library:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.16.7/xlsx.js"></script>
```

I get the file with an html input control:

```
var project;
$(':file').on('change', function () {
   var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.xlsx|.xls)$/;
   var filename = this.files[0].name.toLowerCase();
   var exceljson;
   if (regex.test(filename)) {
      if (filename.indexOf(".xlsx") > 0) {
         if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
               var data = e.target.result;
               var workbook = XLSX.read(data, { type: 'binary' });
               var sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;
               exceljson = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[y]);
            }
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.files[0]);
         }
      }
   }
   project = {
      id: dt.rows('.selected').data()[0].id,
      projectname: dt.rows('.selected').data()[0].projectname,
      file: exceljson
   }
   $.ajax({
      url: urlBack + '/******/importData',
      type: 'POST',
      headers: { "userId": ******, "token": ****** },
      contentType: 'application/json',
      data: JSON.stringify(project),
      success: function (result) {
         $('#table').DataTable().ajax.reload(null, false);
         $('.modal').modal('hide');
         swal(swalProjectAdded, "", "success");
      },
      error: function (result) {
         $('#table').DataTable().ajax.reload(null, false);
         $('.modal').modal('hide');
         swal(swalError, "", "error");
      }
   });
});
$(':file').trigger("click");
```

but when I run it I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find file [Content_Types].xml in zip
    at getzipfile (xlsx.js:2928)
    at getzipstr (xlsx.js:2939)
    at parse_zip (xlsx.js:20612)
    at read_zip (xlsx.js:20946)
    at Object.readSync [as read] (xlsx.js:21012)
    at FileReader.reader.onload (projects:189)
```

I have followed the instructions to run the library so I don't understand what's happening.